# SQL - Copy data partially from a row and adding it to another row

Tags: sql

Like the title states, I'd like to know if it's possible( and if so, how?) to take the first 3 letters from one row and add it in front of existing data in another row.

So instead of:

10213           Maria Barones       van          Winteroy

I'd like to have:

Win10213    Maria Barones       van          Winteroy

Like in the picture provided.
[image]

Comment: Yes it's surely possible with simple string concatenation in an `UPDATE` statement.  What RDBMS do you use?

Comment: For the future, rather than an image, this is much better represented as text.  Paste it into the editor, highlight and click the `{}` button or ctl-k to format it as a code block which will preserve whitespace and keep it looking like a table.

Comment: The highlighted picture doesn't convey what you want to do.  What column from what row do you want to change in what other row?  It can help to show the original data and the desired results.  Also, tag the question with the database you are using.

Comment: Still not clear. The first two rows that don't begin with letters... Do you want to put letters from the other rows onto those? How do you choose which other rows are used? Both an input and an output sample are needed for us to fully understand.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to append the first 3 chars of column 4 to the data in column1 for each row in the table. If yes, the below updated query will do

UPDATE TABLENAME SET COLUMN1 = SUBSTRING(COLUMN4,1,3)+COLUMN1